# Custom Elements create in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any known issues with custom elements created like so:

```
var body = document.body;
var spann = document.createElement("spann");
body.appendChild(spann);
```

in modern browsers, IE8+, Chrome 29+, FF 38+, Safari 8+

Comment: Did you mean `span`?

Comment: what do you mean by issues? it works fine in all those browsers, should behave just like a `<span>`... If you want to give it extra capabilities, use `document.registerElement()` before `document.createElement()`

Comment: also note that while your code will work, hard-coding a `<spann>hello</spann>` into HTML won't reflect CSS rules in IE8, eg. `spann{color:red;}`; it needs the `document.createElement()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues, what you have shown will work.

You are creating an HTML5 element if it is not one of the original set of elements. Keep in mind that your `spann` element with actually be styled like the default HTML5 element, which is essentially a span; no padding or margin, display inline.